# Why do these quotationmarks break my code within HTML, but work via PHP echo?

Tags: php, html, quotation-marks

This works:

```
<?php echo "\"" . $content . "\""; ?>
```

This doesn't 500 Internal Server Error:

```
"<?php echo $content; ?>"
```

**Why?** Thank you!

I'm using PHPStorm and MAMP.

Answer (score -1):

Obviously the second will show you error. Because the second one is not even PHP code. It's simply a string. See carefully, the first one you told the server that it's a PHP code which started with `<?php` and ended with `?>`.

But in the second code, you wrote `<?php` tag inside the quotation. So server doesn't know that it has a PHP code inside. May be you got my point.

Comment: sorry, I didn't want to provide the full quote.

The whole thing is within <html>..<body>..

Comment: Yes I understand but are you sure that in your HTML page, you just wrote `"<?php echo $content; ?>"` . PHP code within double-quote?

Comment: No, there is more code of course. I'm just wondering what the difference between my two examples is.